# Need Scraped Data in Excel Instead of Command Prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, extract

I need to do what is probably very simple for an experienced coder. My Python program successfully Running but I Need that data in Excel Instead Command Prompt.

```py
for users in soup.find_all(class_="user-list-item py-4 d-flex hx_hit-user"):
    print(users.text)
    print("+-"*30,"\n\n")  #Line Change or Another Data
```

This code print Data in as it is available in Web page.

Comment: `pandas` to convert to `csv`

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the many many third party libraries available in python to write excel sheets. You can try open `openpyxl` or may be `xlsxwriter`

Using `openpyxl`

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

users = soup.find_all(class_="user-list-item py-4 d-flex hx_hit-user")
for i,user in enumerate(users):
    ws[f'A{i}'] = user.text

wb.save('output.xlsx')
```

Using `xlsxwriter`

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('output.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

users = soup.find_all(class_="user-list-item py-4 d-flex hx_hit-user")
for i,user in enumerate(users):
    worksheet.write(f'A{i}', user.text)

workbook.close()
```